# Що роблять з асфальтом: кладуть/стелять/ложать?

Tags: вживання-слів

Як правильно сказати: [асфальт](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1792&page=80) кладуть, стелять чи ложать?

СУМ-11

> [Ложити](http://sum.in.ua/s/lozhyty) Те саме, що класти 1, 2.
>
> [Класти](http://sum.in.ua/s/klasty) 1. Поміщати в що-, куди-небудь; розміщувати десь. 2.
>   Надавати комусь, чомусь лежачого положення
>
> [Стелити](http://sum.in.ua/s/stelyty) 1. Класти, розкладати що-небудь на якійсь поверхні або
>   вкриваючи поверхню чогось; слати. 4. Робити покриття, кладучи щільно в
>   ряд дошки, колоди і т. ін.

На мою думку, правильно може бути "стелити асфальт", якщо врахувати четверте значення слова "стелити". Однак в Google пошуку можна зустріти всі три варіанти поєднання слів. Як правильно утворити словосполучення?

Answer (score 8):

Ложать-це суржик, а стелити можна скатертину. Асфальт кладуть. 
Додам приклади з українських ЗМІ:

«У Києві асфальт кладуть прямо на сніг». УКРІНФОРМ.
«На Волині селяни зняли відео , як робітники крадуть асфальт просто на шар снігу». Телеканал Україна.

Comment: Дякую за надану відповідь. Але хочу сказати, що на цьому сайті не заохочуються відповіді чи думки, висловлені без підкріплення джерелами чи аргументами. І хоча Ви надали приклади вживання словосполучення «класти асфальт» (звісно, було б краще оформити їх як веб-посилання на статті/відеосюжети, але то вже другорядне), але Ви не навели жодних підтверджень, що «ложать — це суржик» і «стелити можна [лише?] скатертину».

Answer (score 7):

На мою думку, "ложити асфальт" -- це щось розмовне, на грані суржику.

"Класти (укладати) асфальт", "стелити асфальт" якось краще звучить
(як і СУМівські [приклади](http://sum.in.ua/s/asfaljt): "заливати асфальтом", "покривати асфальтом").
"Мостити асфальт" теж непогано звучить.

Але то так, треба подивитися до якихось словників...

Ось трохи погрався з [ГРАКом](http://uacorpus.org/):

- ложити/положити — [([lemma="ложити|положити"] [lemma="асфальт"]) | ([lemma="асфальт"] [lemma="ложити|положити"])](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=([lemma=%22%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22])+|+([lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%22])) — 0 результатів;
- мостити — [([lemma="мостити"] [lemma="асфальт"]) | ([lemma="асфальт"] [lemma="мостити"])](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=([lemma=%22%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22])+|+([lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%22])) — 0 результатів;
- стелити/встелити — [([lemma="стелити|встелити"] [lemma="асфальт"]) | ([lemma="асфальт"] [lemma="стелити|встелити"])](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=([lemma=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22])+|+([lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22]+[lemma=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%22])) — 6 результатів (1981–2017);
- класти/покласти — [([lemma="класти|покласти"] [lemma="асфальт"]) | ([lemma="асфальт"] [lemma="класти|покласти"])](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=([lemma=%22%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22])+|+([lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22])) — 18 результатів (1976–2018);
- вкладати/укладати/вкласти/укласти — [([lemma="вкладати|укладати|вкласти|укласти"] [lemma="асфальт"]) | ([lemma="асфальт"] [lemma="вкладати|укладати|вкласти|укласти"])](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=([lemma=%22%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8|%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8|%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22])+|+([lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8|%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8|%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22])) — 4 результати (2006–2017);
- викласти — [([lemma="викласти"] [lemma="асфальт"]) | ([lemma="асфальт"] [lemma="викласти"])](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=([lemma=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22])+|+([lemma=%22%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22])) — 1 результат (2015).

Comment: Додам, що саме слово _[ложити](http://sum.in.ua/s/lozhyty)_ вважається розмовним (див. також [тут](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/); а із СУМ-20 зовсім виключене). Тож не дивно, що й словосполучення _ложити асфальт_ може бути лише розмовним.

Answer (score 7):

В професійній літературі частіше вживають варіант "укладати асфальт". Наприклад: "укладання нижнього й вирівнюючого шару асфальту", "технологія укладання асфальтобетонної суміші". Перевірочне слово [асфальтоукладач](http://sum.in.ua/s/asfaljtoukladach) - машина для рівномірного розподілення й укладання асфальту.

Comment: Між іншим, хоча можна й писати "**в**кладати асфальт" (замість "**у**-"), але форми "асфальто**в**кладач" і "асфальто**в**кладальник" у словниках чомусь відсутні.